# LINQ to SQL compare nullable in subquery

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, npgsql

I fail to translate a sql query to a linq query that could calculate some stock.

This is my test query that I'm trying to convert to a linq query.

```
SELECT 
    i.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(t.*) FROM tickets t 
        WHERE t.starttime::time = i.sessionstarttime::time 
        AND t.starttime::date = '2018-04-06'::date) 
    as stock
FROM items I
-- note that the hardcoded date ('2018-04-06') is a function parameter
```

( **tl;dr;** how would you convert this PostgreSQL query to LINQ? )

My attempts so far are the variations of the following query:

```
var items = await _context.Items.Select(x => new Item
{
    Id = x.Id,
    IsTicket = x.IsTicket,
    Name = x.Name,
    Price = x.Price,
    SaleItems = x.SaleItems,
    SessionStartTime = x.SessionStartTime,
    DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
    DateEdit = x.DateEdit,
    UserIdCreated = x.UserIdCreated,
    UserIdEdited = x.UserIdEdited,
    // calculate stock in subquery
    Stock = _context.Tickets.Count(
        t => t.StartTime.Date == ticketDate
        && x.SessionStartTime.HasValue 
        && t.StartTime.Hour == x.SessionStartTime.Value.Hours // this is the part that is failing
        && t.State != TicketState.Canceled)
}).ToListAsync();
```

**t.StartTime** is Datetime and **x.SessionStartTime** is Nullable Timespan

So when I comment the line `&& t.StartTime.Hour == x.SessionStartTime.Value.Hours` everything is fine, but with it I get warnings that it could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. But I don't want to download the whole ticket table just to count them.

The `t.StartTime.Hour` part is fine, I tried to perform static comparisons with both parameters. `t.StartTime.Hour == 5` was translated without any problems, but `x.SessionStartTime.Value.Hours == 5` failed to translate.

Also the problematic part in the application output:

```
([t].StartTime.Hour == Convert([x].SessionStartTime, TimeSpan).Hours))
```

So I guess that convert part is failing.

So what I'm missing and how I could work around this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update:**

After experimenting a bit I have found two workarounds, that I wouldn't call the answers.

First I noticed that EF is trying to convert `Nullable<TimeSpan>` to a regular `TimeSpan` from the mentioned output: `([t].StartTime.Hour == Convert([x].SessionStartTime, TimeSpan).Hours))`

I thought I could prevent that conversion by converting to a string and comparing the strings (I have a feeling this will bite me in the future):

```
t.StartTime.ToString().Contains(x.SessionStartTime.ToString())
```

The second workaround is only viable for my scenario since I know the items query is final and I can materialise it without calculated `Stock`, and then loop through the results and calculate it on a separate query. But this seems to add additional calls to the database and sacrifice some performance.

```
foreach(var x in items.Where(x=>x.SessionStartTime.HasValue))
{
    // accessing the t.StartTime.TimeOfDay property seems to fail the LINQ to SQL as well
    var hours = x.SessionStartTime.Value.Hours;
    var minutes = x.SessionStartTime.Value.Minutes;
    x.Stock = _context.Tickets.Count(t => t.StartTime.Date == ticketDate 
                                        && t.StartTime.Hour == hours 
                                        && t.StartTime.Minute == minutes);
}
```

Comment: You can not use ".Hours" on nullable DateTime, because if it's null, it will not have the Hours property. You need to ensure that your DateTime is not null to use its properties.

Comment: Rereading your question : why are you trying to make an equality with DateTime and TimeSpan ? This not sounds logic does it ?

Comment: Why are you just testing the `Hour` and not `Time` in the LINQ versus the SQL?

Comment: Does EF Core translate `HasValue`? Perhaps you could replace with `x.SessionStartTime != null`?

Comment: @NetMage well, I have tried comparing Time with TimeOfDay, as well as replacing ```HasValue``` with ```!= null```. I'm comparing TimeSpan with DateTime, because I'm checking if ticket starts at the same time as the item.
Now after the weekend I guess I should just split the field in the database from DateTime to Date and Time.

Comment: I would use a range check here: `t.StartTime > minTime && t.StartTime <= maxTime`. I don't know how PostgreSql deals with expressions like `t.StartTime.Date` but chances are it isn't sargeable.